# How to make the same font size?

Tags: fontsize, text

I have a question, why it's a difference font size of "name" and "name of department"? And how to make it the same?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\large {\textsc{  \underline{ Ivanov I.I. } }}}  \\
{\textsc{  (name) }} \\
{\large{\textsc{  \underline{ { Department №1  }}} \\
{\textsc{ (name of the department)   }}  \\
{\large{\textsc{ \underline{  Manager    }}}}  \\
{\textsc{(job desription) }}  \\
{\large {\textsc{  \underline{tuesday is a good day}  }}} \\
{\textsc{ (reason)  }} \\
{\large {\textsc{   \underline{ base }}} \\
{\textsc{ (original reason) }} \\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't ignore errors, you have missing closing braces. (And you could avoid quite a number of braces easily,)

Comment: @Rico yes, you are right, my problem was because I missed braces.

Answer (score 1):

In `\textsc` (small caps) lowercase letters are represented by smaller capitals than uppercase letters. In your text `name of the department` is of the same height as `epartment` from the word `Department` in previous line. Well, the real height depend on the version of closing braces, as we can see in two initial positions.

Answer (score 1):

The probem was that I miss braces, so the correct code should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\large {\textsc{  \underline{ Ivanov I.I. } }}}  \\
{\textsc{  (name) }} \\
{\large{\textsc{  \underline{ Department №1 } }}} \\
{\textsc{ (name of the department)   }}  \\
{\large{\textsc{ \underline{  Manager    } }}}  \\
{\textsc{(job desription) }}  \\
{\large {\textsc{  \underline{tuesday is a good day}  }}} \\
{\textsc{ (reason)  }} \\
{\large {\textsc{   \underline{ base } }}} \\
{\textsc{ (original reason) }} \\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Now it looks correctly, "name" and "name of the department" have the same font size.[image]

Comment: that fixes the error but the markup and linespacing is still in correct you have selected `\large` text but just locally within the line so you are selecting \large text on a normal baseline which is why the spacing is wrong, also you should usse `\textsc{(reason) }` not `\textsc{(reason) }` as the white space places spurious white space in the output, you don't see it here as the line is short and centred but if it was not centered or if it was longer text it would spoil the alignment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment! So how correctly use \large? "also you should usse \textsc{(reason) } not \textsc{(reason) }" what is the difference between   \textsc{(reason) }  and textsc{(reason) } ?

Comment: I'd just use `\large` once at the start (and `{\normalsize....abc}` on the lines with smaller text. for space it's the difference between `helloworld` and `hello world`  white space in tex is not just pretty printing the source code, it is an instruction to add an inter-word space.